# Should I use "Title" or "Heading 1" style for chapter title in Word 2016 document?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, text-formatting, styles, microsoft-word-2016

In my current document I've done two things:

1. Customised the "Heading 1/2/3/..." and "Title" styles.
2. Defined a new multi-level list style to use my customised "Heading x" and "Title" styles so that level 1 in the list uses the "Title" style, level 2 uses "Heading 1", level 3 uses "Heading 2", and so on.

Right now I am using level 1 (in "Title" style) in my multi-level list as chapter headings, and level 2 (in "Heading 1" style) as section headings within the chapter. However, I discovered that when I insert a Table of Contents, the chapter headings (the ones in "Title" style) *do not* show up in the table. I guess this means that Word 2016 only uses "Heading x" styles when constructing table of contents???

What I want my table of contents is for it to show chapters *and* the section headings within each one.

What should I do?

Should I re-define my multi-level list so that the top level (which I want to use as chapter titles) uses the "Heading 1" style instead of the "Title" style? Or is there another way to tell Word 2016 that I want chapter titles in the table of contents?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just have to insert a custom TOC that is based the Title style in addition to Heading styles, and then make a few other adjustments.

1. On the **References** tab, click **Table of Contents** > **Custom Table of Contents**.
2. In the **Table of Contents** dialog box, click **Options**.
3. In the **Table of Contents Options** dialog box, under the **Styles** check box (which should be selected by default), scroll down the list until you find the **Title** style.
4. Enter **1** in the field to the right of the style name.
5. Scroll back up until you find the heading styles.
6. Change the **1** to the right of **Heading 1** to **2**, change the **2** next to **Heading 2** to **3**, and so on.
7. Click **OK** twice to insert the TOC.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed instructions, it worked for me! I do wonder, however, whether the builtin "Title" style is canonically intended for use as chapter titles, the title for the whole document/book, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The title style is for the document title.

Headings are what you should use for chapters, sections, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of sections being subordinate to chapters, Chapters should be Heading 1 and Sections should be Heading 2.

The reason Title did not show up in the TOC is because it is not an Outlined Style. Heading 1 is an outline level 1 style, Heading 2 is an outline level 2 style.

Assuming your TOC is set to show outline levels 1 & 2, then it all will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several very good reasons to use the built-in Heading styles 1-9 (even if you've changed them to look the way you need them).  Using the Title style as Heading 1 is going to cause you problems with things like captioning, footnotes, lists of tables and figures, etc.  I recommend you return to the Heading 1 style as your top-level heading.